# Magento product import fails to load images

Tags: php, magento, import

Trying to import 800 simple products to the database.

Cant use:
System > Import Export > Dataflow profiles:
Error: Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"

Tried importing via System > Import Export > Import.
imports the products but the images are not linked: "No Image".

I tried downloading http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fast-products-import.html but that doesn't apply the categories however the images show.

is there a way to import the products with one plugin and batch update either the category or image with the other?

i can quite easily make a CSV with SKU and category column

Comment: Open your CSV in text editor,  not in OpenOffice etc. And check if CSV is properly made

Comment: And what path are you supplying to image?

Comment: The images are uploaded to media/import/ and the file is reffered to in the csv as /skusku.jpg . The simple magento importer checks the file and says its ok.

Answer (score 1):

you can use MAGMI for import of products & category http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

it's really good one for import purpose, I have imported around 16000 products using it.